# Run PendingIntent in exact time

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

Everybody.

I've got this code snippet.

```
pending_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + runDelay, pending_intent);
```

I want to get rid of System.currentTimeMillis() + runDelay, and pass just runDelay variable intofunction, does someone know what I should do?

P.S. I need code to be API8

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why?  If this works, why spend the time and effort?  If you really hate it that much, write a function that encapsulates that bit of logic.

Comment: I want to be independent from current time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'independent from current time'? This doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: by Independing I mean that I shouldn't care about current time, program should do same instructions without calling System.currentTime(). It can be simple timer that starts, after 'runDelay' time it will invoke intent. So my question is Can I do it

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are asking. You've got code that works and I don't see what is wrong with it. There are lots of alternatives, and they all have pros and cons. You can post a Runnable to a Handler with a delay. In the Runnable send the `Intent`. You can start a Thread that sleeps or a use a TimerTask. The advantage of using `AlarmManager` is that the `Intent` will get launched even if your application isn't running.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `TimePickerDialog` to get the `runDelay` from user to do so

**class variable:**

```
private TimePickerDialog time_picker;
private Calendar targetCal;
```

**A class constructor**

```
public YOurClassName() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    }
```

**inside onCreate() or onActivityCreated():**

```
time_picker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), mTimeSetListener,
            mHour, mMinute, false);
```

**Inside the class:**

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        // the callback received when the user "sets" the TimePickerDialog in
        // the dialog
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {

            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = min;

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            targetCal = calSet;
            }
    };
```

use the `targetCal` in your code like this

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
```

I hope this would help you

Comment: thanks man, but it's not exactly what I want, as I say in previous my comment, I need to be independent from Current Time. I think there should be some mechanism, that will be triggered automatically after

Comment: If you don't get the currentTime of the system then how will you set the alarm at a specified time... I'm not getting exactly what you want @Jabberwocky

Comment: I ask about "Are there other ways to start pending intent, without using System.currentTime()?"